# MVC5 Authentication cannot save UseCookieAuthentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with MVC 5 Authentication
After success login, i think i cannot save UseCookieAuthentication.

- My Startup code:

> ```
>     public partial class Startup
> {
>     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>     {
>          app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
>                 {
>                     AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
>                     LoginPath = new PathString("/MyAccount/Login")
>                 });
>                 // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
>                 app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
>     }
> }
> ```

- My login controler:

  ```
  public ActionResult Login(Login l, string ReturnUrl="")
  {
      using (CBDB2012Entities dc = new CBDB2012Entities())
      {
          var user = dc.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(l.Username) && a.Password.Equals(l.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
          if (user != null)
          {
              FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, l.RememberMe);
              if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
              {
                  return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
              }
              else
              {
                  return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "MyAccount");
              }
          }
      }
      ModelState.Remove("Password");
      return View();
  }
  ```

after login, it RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "MyAccount");
But in MyProfile view, i cannot see anything about user and i cann't access to contac page with  [Authorize]:

-Contact controler

> ```
>     [Authorize]
>     public ActionResult Contact()
>     {
>         ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
>
>         return View();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I has test via session in login control, and it work fine:

```
var user = dc.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(l.Username) && a.Password.Equals(l.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, l.RememberMe);
                Session["loginname"] = user.Employee.FirstName;

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "MyAccount");
                }
            }
```

i can get Session["loginname"] in view from database.